# Why is $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \Biggr(\tan^{-1}{\Big(\dfrac{b}{x}\Big)} - \tan^{-1}{\Big(\dfrac{a}{x}\Big)}\Biggr)= 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

For $$f(x) = \tan^{-1}{\Big(\frac{b}{x}\Big)} - \tan^{-1}{\Big(\frac{a}{x}\Big)}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are differently valued constants, why is $\lim_{x\to0^+}= 0$? I understand that separately both expressions tend toward $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ for any value of $a$ or $b$, but surely the expressions cannot both give $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ for the same value of $x$ at any given time?

Comment: The point is that both the functions are close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ when $x$ is close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ although the values are not the same. This is what we need. If you work through the $\epsilon$, $\delta$ proof of the result $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)+\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ provided the limits in the RHS exist, you will understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the result holds only if $ab>0$ (ie $a, b$ are of same sign). And your argument is correct. Both the terms tend to $\pi/2$ (or to $-\pi/2$) hence their difference tends to $0$.

One can not expect that a function tending to $0$ should be identically equal to $0$. For example $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{n}=0$, yet $x^{n} \neq 0$ if $\neq 0$. Hence both the terms may give different values so that their difference is non-zero and yet this non-zero difference can tend to $0$. This is just a basic interplay of arithmetic inequalities and nothing more. If this looks a bit astonishing / unbelievable then you need to convince yourself that limits are nothing more than appreciation of inequalities of a certain type.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on the idea that the relationship between a and b would determine just how close a value to 0 the function could give, but of course then I've ceased to think in terms of limits and have missed the point!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the problem using Taylor series around $x=0^+$ and formally get $$\tan^{-1}{\Big(\frac{a}{x}\Big)}=\frac{\pi  \sqrt{a^2}}{2 a}-\frac{x}{a}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Simplify and use the other term.

Answer (score 1):

Something which may be useful here :

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*$,

$$ \arctan x + \arctan \frac{1}{x} = \text{sign}(x) \frac{\pi}{2}$$.

Thus, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$,

$$f(x) = \arctan(\frac{a}{x})-\arctan(\frac{b}{x})$$

$$ = (\text{sign}(a)\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\frac{x}{a}))-(\text{sign}(b)\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\frac{x}{b}))$$

$$ \underset{x \to 0^+}\to  (\text{sign}(a)-\text{sign}(b))\frac{\pi}{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MTV to see it. For a differentiable function $g$ holds
$g(x_1)-g(x_2)=g'(\xi)(x_1-x_2)$ for some $\xi\in (x_1,x_2)$.

Now define $g(y)=\arctan(y)$ and you get 
$$
f(x)=g\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)-g\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)=g'(\xi)\left(\frac{b}x-\frac{a}x\right)=\frac1{1+\xi^2}\cdot\frac{b-a}{x}
$$
where $\xi\in\left(\frac{a}{x},\frac{b}{x}\right)$. Hence
$$
\frac{(b-a)x}{x^2+b^2}=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)^2}\cdot\frac{b-a}x\leq \frac1{1+\xi^2}\cdot\frac{b-a}{x}\leq
\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^2}\cdot\frac{b-a}x=\frac{(b-a)x}{x^2+a^2}.
$$
So we can conclude
$$
0=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{(b-a)x}{x^2+b^2}\leq \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)\leq \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{(b-a)x}{x^2+a^2}=0.
$$
The function must not achieve the limit for some final value. But from
$$
\frac{(b-a)x}{x^2+b^2}\leq f(x)\leq \frac{(b-a)x}{x^2+a^2}
$$
you can see that the value of $f$ becomes smaller for large $x$ and goes to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

Let $a,b,x \gt 0.$

$\alpha :=\arctan (a/x),$ $ \beta:= \arctan (b/x)$,

$\alpha, \beta \in (0,π/2)$.

$y(x):= \beta - \alpha$.

$\tan(\beta - \alpha)= \dfrac{ \tan(\beta) - \tan(\alpha)}{1+\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}.$

$g(x):= \tan(y(x)) = \dfrac{(b/x -a/x)}{1 + ba/x^2)};$

$g(x) =  \dfrac{(b-a)x}{x^2+ba}$.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} g(x)= 0.$

Considering the limit in the composite function $\arctan[g(x)] = y(x)$.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} y(x) =$

$\arctan(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}g(x))= \arctan(0) = 0.$

N.B. last line: Continuity of $\arctan$ is used.